# Getting entity which has some elements

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a Book entity which has a One2Many relationship with the Page entity. I wanted to create a query which retrieved all the books which had at least one page. I did:

```
       $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Book')
        ->createQueryBuilder('b');          
        ->leftJoin('b.pages','p')
        ->having($qb->expr()->gt($qb->expr()->count('p'), 0));

       $books = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

The problem is that, although there are many books which have pages, this query only returns a single book.

The query created is:

```
SELECT b FROM Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Book b LEFT JOIN b.pages p HAVING COUNT(p) > 0
```

which looks fine to me. Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler to use

```
->innerJoin('b.pages','p')
```

instead of

```
->leftJoin('b.pages','p')
```

you don't need aggregate function. In short: this innerjoin will return only Books that can be joined with at least one Page.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `groupBy` as you are using aggregate function. e.g.

```
  $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Book')
    ->createQueryBuilder('b');          
    ->leftJoin('b.pages','p')
    ->groupBy('b.id')
    ->having($qb->expr()->gt($qb->expr()->count('p'), 0));
```